# Is there a command to import an SPSS data frame (.sav) using dask?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, spss

I am trying to import multiple dataframes using Dask; however, it seems that unlike pandas, Dask doesn't have any commands to do so. Or at least I haven't been able to find a way to do it within its documentation/examples.

I know that I could transform the databases to csv or chunk it, but I'd like to rule out this alternative due to the complexity of the database.

Is there any command or plugin that allows me to parallelize the import with dask?

Answer (score 0):

Dask dataframe doesn't support `pandas.read_spss`. There was a user with a similar problem here (reading sas format with dask): https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1233